# Creating State that's inside of an array

Tags: reactjs, components

How would I create states in React for firstName and lastName which are both inside an array? I have tasks: [] as an array state but I need firstName and lastName so I can pass them as props. I'm doing it to make my form sticky for edit.

```
 _id
    :5f17c1913361b03a189ff60d
    tasks
    :
    Array
        0
        :
        Object
            firstName
            :"added Creator"
            lastName
            :"added Creator lastName"
        1
        :
        Object
    additional
    :"this is a test"
    creator
    :5f10cbe01e281a041cbbfe77
    date
    :2020-07-22T04:33:21.327+00:00
    __v
    :0
```

My this.state:

```
this.state = {
      tasks: [],
      comment: "",
      first: "", //do I loop tasks to get first and lastname?
      last: ""
    };
```

My componentDidMount is below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const res = axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/api/dashboard")
      .then(response => {
       
        this.setState({
          tasks: response.data,
          comment: response.data.additional
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many objects then you need to have loop and push the names as array in first and last. If you have only one you can do this

```
response.data.tasks[0].firstName
response.data.tasks[0].lastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You already all data fetching from server. You don't need to create dublicate field in states.  I think, you should set a state all fetching data and modify it. After you finish at this data, you push or record server easily. So i show that blow:

```
componentDidMount() { 
const res = axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/dashboard").then(response => 
    { this.setState({ fetchData: response.data})
})}
```

you can update this record of user like:

```
onUserNameChangeHandler = (firstName) => {
   this.setState( prevState => {
      prevState.fetchData.tasks[0].firstName = firstName;
return {...prevState}
})
}
```

now you can easily update or save your record.